# Cxx11 ABI for a single function call?

Tags: c++11, preprocessor, compatibility, abi, gcc5

Is it possible to define a piece of your code to be compiled with Cxx11 but the rest is using the compatibility ABI of libstdc++6 ?

Example:

```
// Compatibility ABI
int myvar = 0;
std::string mystring = "hello";

// This method is from another library
// that has been compiled with Cxx11
call_routine_ext_library(mystring);

// Compatibility ABI
myvar += 2;
```

My whole system is compiled in compatibility mode except one external library compiled with Cxx11.
Does there exist a preprocessor that allows you to handpick certain part of your code to be compiled using the new ABI just as you would have defined D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 on the compiler line ?

The error I get when calling the method *call_routine_ext_library* is:

```
undefined reference to `call_routine_ext_library(std::string const&)'
```

because the library contains this:

```
call_routine_ext_library(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>)
```

So I was hoping I could force the compiler to use Cxx11 mode when compiling the string I pass into that method. 
Are there any means of linking against a binary compiled with Cxx11 when your code is compiled without it ?

Comment: So - two compilers? Maybe it's best to make a C-level wrapper, and call via (eg) cdecl passing char*s etc.

Comment: @David M If you mean that does something like: `const char* tmpstr = mystring.c_str(); call_routine_ext_library(tmpstr)` then that doesn't work either

Comment: And `extern "C"`? So all C++ compilers link using C mode, not C++ or a specific C++ ABI? Are you familiar with [this advice on mixing C and C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)?